# What is the easiest way to insert a PDF page in a Word file?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

Let me explain; I have a PDF document (some legal stuff), not made by me. The author of the document has no objections, and I need to insert a few pages of that document in a Word file I'm writing (in an Appendix).

What would be the easiest way to do that ?

*(Export to HTML and then insert a whole image is the only way I could think of. Anyone got any better ideas ?)*

Comment: This is pretty old, but if you split the pages out of the entire pdf, you can `insert - object - create from file`

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about the *easiest* but the highest fidelity would probably be to load the PDF file into Adobe Illustrator, save the page as an EPS file, and insert that ("Insert" -> "Picture" -> "From file...") onto a blank Word page.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't have Illustrator but I used Acrobat (not the Reader) and exported the pdf to an eps file. It worked and the text of the resulting page is so sharp and legible - much more than taking a screenshot and copy pasting it.

Comment: this no longer works as microsoft disabled EPS support in office

Answer (score 3):

While you can create an image and then insert it, it will likely look of poor quality (pixelation). I don't know if you have a requirement that the document you're working on be completed in a Word-compatible format, but if you have a PDF editor I would complete the document (possibly using blank spacer pages if you need accurate page numbering), use a PDF printer to turn it into a PDF, and then splice in the extra pages afterwards. Not sure about easiest, but it'll probably have the highest quality. Easiest would probably be to open the PDF, hit <kbd>PrntScrn</kbd>, paste into Paint, crop borders, then copy+paste from paint to Word.

Comment: cropping is impossible in paint...how do you do that?

Comment: The Paint version included with Windows 7 supports cropping - You can use a program called Paint.Net in previous versions of windows.

Comment: I crop all the time in Paint for XP.  Get the picture in Paint, ctrl-A to select the whole picture and move the picture to crop on the top left of the screen.  Then find the "one pixel" horizontal and vertical adjustments to crop the rest of the picture.  It only takes a second or two.

Comment: @wbeard52 +1 *Ninja hacks*

Comment: @wbeard52 I still use that method in Windows 8. It's easier of you use the bottom right corner to do both horizontal and vertical adjustments at once.

Comment: @Marco Huh? The proposed solution was to convert the Word document into PDF and append the first PDF to it. Assuming a majority of the word document is text, that actually will remain vector content. In any case, there will not be noticeable degradation to the human eye. (This is of course, dependent upon the word-to-pdf creator that you use. Saving a Word document as .pdf from inside Word will create a vector PDF)

Answer (score 2):

I do this frequently.

1. Open the pdf in Adobe Acrobat.
2. Select "Document", "OCR Text Recognition", "Recognize Text Using OCR"
3. Wait for Adobe to scan and format the pdf into text.
4. Highlight the desired text and cut/paste it into the word document.
5. Review and correct spelling and formatting that may have been lost in the OCR conversion.

This only works with text.  You will still want to insert graphic pdf's as pictures.

YZ1

Answer (score 1):

You might have faced difficulty in copy pasting from PDF to Word (MS Office 2007) while preparing Report and Your "Research  Papers" :-P. Here I am providing an easy tutorial for doing that in an easier way.

1. Open a Blank New Document
2. Copy and paste the content from PDF to Word document.
3. Select the content and press "ALT+SHIFT+CTRL+S"
4. A New window will be appeared on the left side. This is called "Styles" window.
5. Select "Clear all" options from that.
6. Now press "CTRL+F".
7. Select "Replace" in the newly opened window.
8. Type "^p" in "Find What" area.
9. Type a "SPACE" (Not the word Space) in the "Replace with" area.
10. Click on "Replace All"
11. Click "OK".
12. Clcik "Close".
13. You have done with that.
14. "Happy Copy Pasting"

Note: By seeing the number of steps, you may feel that it is difficult and I will go with the old "Delete Space" Method.
But if you try it once, you will see it very easy and useful. It is suitable for big document. Always do this formatting work in a new Blank document, otherwise it may affect the report which you are preparing.

Comment: @SanderSteffann: It also doesn't matter. "user contributions licensed under cc-wiki with attribution required"

Answer (score 1):

Okay we just had to solve this exact problem and the easiest solution we found is the following (forget EPS, exports etc etc...). This solution makes use of ms office 2010 and Adobe Acrobat Reader 11 (XI).

- Open you PDF documents
- Select the area (or page) you want to copy with the (Edit -> Take Snapshot)

This will save the current selection to the clipboard.

- Zoom to 800% (or whatever zoom your computer hardware allows - this was an intel i5 with 8GB of RAM and a full A4-size document)
- Hit `CRTL+C` (copy)
- Move to your Word document (or open a new one)
- Paste (or `CTRL+V`)

Note that this method give you a really high resolution and is going to slow down your system a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In a Word document, Click Insert > Object

2.In the Object dialog box, click Create from File and then click Browse.

3.Find the PDF you want to insert, and then click Insert.

4.In the Object dialog box, check Display as icon if you only want to display the PDF icon in your document. Leave it unchecked to display the first page of the PDF.

5.Click OK.

Double-click the PDF object in your document to open and view it in your default PDF reader.

(This method allows preserving quality of the PDF)

Comment: Somehow I'm under the impression that the asker wanted to incorporate the PDF part in a way that his document could be viewed and printed as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Since the author has no objections,Why not this:

1. Open the pdf in Adobe Reader.
2. Open the document in full screen (`Ctrl+L`)
3. Use `Ctrl+1` or `Ctrl+2` to get a preferred view. The page may not be completely displayed.
4. Use `PrntScrn` to copy to clipboard, paste it in MS Powerpoint
5. Back to Adobe Reader, scroll to the "second half"
6. Use `PrntScrn` again to copy to clipboard, paste it in MS Powerpoint
7. Crop and join (place one after another) as required
8. Select both the pictures, `Right Click -> Group`
9. `Right Click -> Save as picture`
10. Insert this picture in your Word doc.

Advantage: You dont need need "new" tools or software (Since you have MS Word, I assume you have Powerpoint also)

I always use Powerpoint in these situations because it has this "Save as picture" feature.

You may also use Paint.NET for the "crop and merge"

I donot recommend MS Paint, the pictures can turn out to be low fidelity or of vary large size. (I have not used the Windows 7 version of paint)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain formatting, the route of splicing the PDF file is probably easiest, as in the other answers. Note that you do not necessarily need Adobe Acrobat to do this, there are other PDF slicing programs out there (see other SU questions).

If you just want the text, there are various tools to extract text from a PDF. That would allow (and force) you to reformat the text as you like. Again, there are various programs available.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Insert - Photo - Pictures from File, choose the pdf file and insert the pages you want one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The free version of Adobe Reader has a tool for this. These are the steps:

1. Open the file in Adobe Reader
2. In Adobe Reader, go to Edit > Take a Snapshot
3. Select what you want by clicking and dragging
4. You will get a message telling your selection has been copied
5. Go to Word and paste like an image

**Important:** The resolution you will get is sensitive to what you see in screen, that is, select in Adobe Reader the zoom value which gives you the quality you want before clicking and dragging. Also, you don't need to see everything in your screen, the Take a Snapshot tool will automatically scroll the page for you as you drag.